# Auto-Completion in Unix VI editor

Tags: variables, unix, autocomplete, vi

After using graphical IDE's like Visual Studio, I'm used to pressing CTRL+Space to auto-complete a variable or function name. Now, I know such a thing isn't completely possible in VI, but I heard there was a list of commands that could be mapped that allowed automatic completion of variables and functions in the current file opened. Does anyone know what this sequence is?

Answer (score 3):

*Just noticed that you said "vi"; I hope that "vim" is also okay.*

It depends on the particular programming language, but in general, the magic word is [Omnicomplete](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Omnicomplete).

Put this into .vimrc:

```
filetype plugin on
set ofu=syntaxcomplete#Complete
```

Press Ctrl+N or Ctrl+P to trigger the completion. This is insanely customizable; you might like the tips [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1386) that make it work more like other IDEs.

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer but unfortunately my workplace only supports VI which doesn't support Omni  :(

Comment: If I were forbidden from using vim, I would look for another job. If I were forbidden from using vim, but using vi was allowed, I would probably explode at my boss, get escorted out of the building, then look for another job.

Comment: I don't understand how you get into such a situation. If you're used to Visual Studio, you're a programmer. I can see how a sysadmin might be required to use vi because it's tiny and ubiquitous and he just needs to tweak a few config files, but---programming? And they won't even allow vim?